# Use of 十年中 to express duration

Tags: grammar

Does 十年中 mean "in ten years"? I found it in this sentence from [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/335890):

> 他十年中第一次回家。
>
> He returned home for the first time in ten years.

It seems like I could use the same pattern to say, "I haven't had a drink in five years." 我五年中没有喝酒。 Does that work?

Comment: Don, your second Chinese example sounds slightly unnatural. I think it has something to do with your English example. In the second example, the "in" indicates a specific *duration* coupled with a *continuous* activity; whereas in the first example, the "in" simply indicates a simple temporal scope with a *non-continuous* activity. The difference is extremely subtle, but when you translate it into Chinese, you cannot use the same structure. I'd say something like: 我五年没喝过酒, essentially removing 中 and adding the perfect tense marker.

Comment: If you want a more 'natural' example, you could say: 我五年没沾过一滴酒. (literally: I haven't touched a single drop of alchohol in five years.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.
中 can be used to express that something happened of didn't happen **within a certain scope or range** or just within something (《现代汉语词典》: 范围内；内部). The range doesn't need to be a time range, but it can be. Furthermore, it can also refer to the future.
So you can say:

- 他预言战争将在下几年中爆发: He predicted that war would break out in the next few years.
  年中
- 在最近若干年中: In recent years
- 在过去一百二十年中，人口已膨胀了十倍: In the past 120 years the population has increased tenfold.
- 过去几年中，许多工人对美术发生了兴趣: Many workers have taken to the arts in the past few years.
- 随后的四十年中，债务人受州法律的保护: For the next 40 years debtors were subject to state laws.

As already mentioned it can also refer to other things than a time range. Some examples:
家中， 水中， 山中， 心中， 队伍中

Answer (score 3):

中 literally means middle. Taken with respect to time or space, it means "within."

So 他十年中第一次回家 means, he returned home once within a [particular] ten year period.

Answer (score 1):

`中` is a redundant word when used in such context. Instead, you could write:

> 他十年第一次回家

and

> 我五年没有喝酒

The reason why `中` is not used to express a period in time is because `中` has another meaning - `middle`.

Example,

> 他在年中考试考不及格。
>
> He failed his mid-year exam.

It is clear to Chinese native speakers when the context is given that the number of years refer to a period in time instead of a specific point in time. So there is no real need to add `中` behind `十年` to express a duration.

However, if you really insist, you can use `来` instead to express duration.

Example,

> 他这十年来都没有回家。
>
> He has never been home during the past ten years.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you mean "should write" or "could write"?

Comment: I mean `中` shouldn't be there. Of course it could be written in many ways. Let me correct that.